# Why is there discrepancy between number of connections in sys.sysprocesses and sys.dm_exec_connections?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

The number of active connections reported by sql server is as follows:

- sys.sysprocesses 154
- sys.dm_exec_connections 125

Why is there discrepancy between number of connections in sys.sysprocesses and sys.dm_exec_connections?

And what is the correct way to retrieve the number of open connections?

Answer (score 4):

First up, it's time to retire [sysprocesses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysprocesses-transact-sql). That is maintained only for backwards compatibility to SQL Server 2000. Microsoft has a [mapping table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/mapping-system-tables-to-system-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). The better choice is [sys.dm_exec_sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql).

However, you will see differences between sys.dm_exec_sessions and [sys.dm_exec_connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-connections-transact-sql) because of various functions.

For example, multiple active result sets (MARS) cause additional connections in sys.dm_exec_connections, more than sys.dm_exec_sessions. On the other hand, other systems, such as service broker, make additional rows in sys.dm_exec_sessions, but not in sys.dm_exec_connections.

In short, the different DMVs are showing different sets of information, and there's not always a one-to-one correlation between them.